# How to resolve error Cannot read property 'crgName' of null

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I get the following error: Cannot read property 'crgName' of null on the following line:

```
{AppState.energyProgram.crgName}
```

below is the code snippet:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  className="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" 
  aria-haspopup="true" 
  aria-expanded="false"
>
  {AppState.energyProgram.crgName}
</button>
```

...so for the particular user I logged in under, the JSON for the object  energyProgram was null, so am attempting to implement a condition that checks if it's null, to still render the page

so I changed:

```
{AppState.energyProgram.crgName}
```

to:

```
{AppState.energyProgram.crgName && AppState.energyProgram.crgName['Name']}
```

...but I still get the error, could I get some help with this please?

Comment: That error message means that ```AppState.energyProgram``` is the thing that's null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test whether `AppState.energyProgram` is truthy and only access/return the value of `AppState.energyProgram.crgName` if so—ergo:

```
{AppState.energyProgram && AppState.energyProgram.crgName}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `AppState.energyProgram.crgName` is undefined, then `AppState.energyProgram.crgName['Name']` will be undefined, as well.

If you run something like `console.log(AppState.energyProgram)` outside what your `render()` function returns, that might help you troubleshoot what that object looks like before rendering.